# The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null. How to solve this error for the list of lists?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have got list of lists and I need to retrieve data from them. I am using Provider for fetching data from the API. So I screated the ExpansionTile with 2 Listview.builder, because I have read that for retrieving data I need to use some loop for each list, e.g Listview.builder. But now it gives me the error

```
"The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length"
```

But when I use print the array isn't null, so I don't get it why I getting this error.

My code is:

```
class _StopScreensState extends State<StopScreens> {
  List<Stop> stop;
  List<Routes> routes;
  List <Arrival> arrivals;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    stop = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context).toList();
    routes = Provider.of<List<Routes>>(context).toList();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    //The list of lists
    Iterable<Common> merge(List<Arrival> arrivals, List<Stop> stop,
        List<Routes> route) sync* {
      for (int i = 0; i < arrivals.length; i++) {
        var fishingTackle = routes.where((v) => v.mrId == arrivals[i].mrId).toList();
        var fishBait = stop.where((v) => v.stId == arrivals[i].stId).toList();
        yield Common(
          id: arrivals[i].mrId,
          typeId: arrivals[i].mrId,
          fishingTackle: fishingTackle,
          fishBait: fishBait,
          time: arrivals[i].taArrivetime,
        );
      }
    }
    
    //the common list for all arrays
    List<Common> common = merge(arrivals, stop, routes).toList();

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Остановки'),
        ),
        body: Provider.value(value: common) == null
            ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: common.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ExpansionTile(title: Text(common[index].fishingTackle[index].mrTitle),
                    children: [
                      ListView.builder(itemCount: stop.length,itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(common[index].fishBait[index].stTitle),
                          leading: Text(common[index].time.toString()),
                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a null list.

Try to always initialized your list with an empty list, so you don't need to handle the null value for each list.

Change:

```
List<Stop> stop;
List<Routes> routes;
List <Arrival> arrivals;
```

to

```
List<Stop> stop = [];
List<Routes> routes = [];
List <Arrival> arrivals = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not assigning anything to `arrivals`